# Map Support in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, dictionary

I am new in `Shell Scripting`, however i am friendly with `Java Maps`. I Just wanted to know that how can i use `Map` facility in `Shell Scripting`. Below is the facility i need to use in shell-

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> users = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    String username = "test_user1";
    String address = "test_user1_address";
    String emailId = "test_user1_emailId";

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add(address);
    values.add(emailId);

    users.put(username, values);

    String anotherUser = "test_user2";

    if (users.containsKey(anotherUser)) {
        System.out.println("Do some stuff here");
    }
```

In short, i want to use a `Map`, which has `String` as `key`, either `Vector` or `ArrayList` as value (otherwise i have live with `Arrays` instead of `ArrayList` and manually take care of `indexes`) , `put` method to `insert` and one more method to check the presence of the `key` in the existing `Map`.

The above code is a sample code.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: (extending the answer below) Since you are coming from Java world, try groovy ( http://groovy.codehaus.org/).  It is nice scripting language on top of jvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash does not support nested structures like this. Either use separate variables for each array, or use something more capable such as Python.

Comment: Okay, can you please elaborate it more `Either use separate variables for each array`?

Comment: `var1=(...) ; var2=(...) ; var3=(...)`

Comment: Hey, I can manage my work with `2D String array` somehow but the `Searching` operation `users.containsKey(anotherUser)` will be too poor. Any better suggesations ?

Comment: See the second part of my answer.